# How to obtain the "nodeValue" by python?

Tags: python, dom, xml-parsing, minidom

I am trying to parse some XML file like following:

```
<foo  
 ...
   </M1>
   <foo2 CHAR="A" NUM="8" TYPE="beta">
    <SEQ>
           12345      
    </SEQ>
    <REGION seq_beg="1" seq_end="8"  >
    <REGION seq_beg="9" seq_end="21">
    <REGION seq_beg="22" seq_end="32">
    <REGION seq_beg="33" seq_end="44">
  </foo2>
```

I have able to use `childNodes[x]` to get everything within the

```
<foo2 ...

</foo2>
```

and use `getElementsByTag("SEQ")` or `getElementsByTag("REGION")`
How I get the value for the `nodeName <foo2>` to print out `CHAR, NLM...etc.`

Comment: I think I know the answer now just use the attributes['xxx'].value;

Comment: You can answer your own question, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: where I can do that? I think I did not check "answer my own question" when I submitted it :-( .....

Comment: Just post an answer as usual. It's an normal answer, but posted by yourself, then you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks ...but it looks like I can only accept my ans in 2days:-(

Answer (score 0):

use the attributes['xxx'].value